# When i play music from my activity music in Backround doesn't stop?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

When I press the play button I want to stop the songs in the background and play my song

This play and pause function :

```
public void play(View view) {
    mp.start();
    if (mp != null && mp.isPlaying()){
        play.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        pause.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }else{
        pause.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        play.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}

public void pause(View view) {
    mp.pause();
    pause.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    play.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use AudioFocus. Official document is [here](https://developer.android.com/training/managing-audio/audio-focus.html)

But if your background Music doesn't use AudioFocus, it doesn't work also. Hopefully, most music application will use AudioFocus to control playback or pause.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stop the music when your application stay on background. You have to control it through [activity life cycle](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html). 
As when application exit foreground it call onPause() and onStop(). You should update your music player status here. Please look at following code:

```
@Override
public void onPause()
{
    super.onPause();
    if(mp.isPlaying())
        mp.stop();
    else
        return;
}

@Override
public void onStop()
{
    super.onStop();
    if(mp.isPlaying())
        mp.stop();
    else
        return;
}
```